# Selecting Data from mulitple tables in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I have multiple tables in `Hive` with different schemas.

I want to select top 20 rows from each table and dump into csv file.

Is there any way to do it. As all I have found is to dump data from a single table to `csv.`

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: A single CSV file or multiple files?

Comment: Can we trust your tables to contain only primitive types (No arrays, structs etc.)?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitzca single CSV file.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Yeah, they contain only primitive types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have different schema.

1.Below sample code will produce multiple csv files.

```
#!/bin/bash

  tbs=$(hive -S -e "show tables")
  for tb in $tbs
  do
    hive -e "set hive.cli.print.header=true; SELECT * FROM $tb LIMIT 20;" | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' > $tb.csv
  done
```

2.Below sample code will produce single csv file.

```
#!/bin/bash

  tbs=$(hive -S -e "show tables")
  for tb in $tbs
  do
    echo "Table Name : "$tb >> sampleData.csv
    hive -e "set hive.cli.print.header=true; SELECT * FROM $tb LIMIT 20;" | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' >> sampleData.csv
  done
```

Comment: Getting better :-) How about using beeline?

Comment: How would I write a similar code to produce a single csv if I wanted a hive script.

Comment: Looping is not possible in hive script. Is there any specific requirement to write in hive script?

Comment: @ManishSaraf Is it possible to show the name of each table and then dump it's contents in the csv.

Comment: Yes it is possible. I have updated script. pls have a look.